# AdaptiveCard not rendering in Bot Framework Emulator / Web Chat

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Really hoping someone can help out on this.

I'm trying to achieve - a no-code chat bot using [QnAMaker.ai](https://QnAMaker.ai) and Azure Bot Services with AdaptiveCards to serve rich content.

I have a knowledgebase set up and published, I have a bot in Azure set up to serve that content and it seems to work okay at the first stage.

Now I'm trying to add AdaptiveCards *without* opening and editing the solution in VSCode - I really want to keep all this contained in a no-code solution.

I Googled how to add custom cards/content and found [this post by LiveTiles](https://help.livetiles.nyc/en/articles/2221360-adaptive-cards) - excellent - I thought, I can just add minified JSON and it will render what I want - lovely stuff!

However; despite there being a live output render on the LiveTiles site, when I take that JSON I cannot get it to render through either Web Chat or the Bot Framework Emulator.

I've tried...

- Copy/pasting the raw JSON into a QnAPair

```
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Image",
                "url": "",
                "size": "stretch",
                "selectAction": {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "Test",
                    "url": "https://www.livetiles.nyc/"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "This is an adaptive card - if this renders it means it's worked!",
                "wrap": true
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Let's get started!",
                "url": "Let's get started!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Copy/pasting minified JSON into a QnAPair

```
{"contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive","content":{"type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"1.0","body":[{"type":"Image","url":"","size":"stretch","selectAction":{"type":"Action.OpenUrl","title":"Test","url":"https://www.livetiles.nyc/"}},{"type":"TextBlock","text":"This is an adaptive card - if this renders it means it's worked!","wrap":true}],"actions":[{"type":"Action.Submit","title":"Let's get started!","url":"Let's get started!"}]}}
```

[image]

- Making a Source Excel File (which includes the JSON) and adding that to the knowledge base

[image]
All my attempts end up with the bot spitting the actual JSON at me when I ask it. Not the lovely rendered card I wanted.

Renders on the LiveTiles site:
[image]

Doesn't render on the Emulator
[image]

Or on the Web Chat
[image]

In QnAMaker.ai Test Function

[image]

Really hoping someone can offer some insight or advice to this.

Comment: What happens when you use Test in the the QnA Portal?

Comment: The same thing is happening when I test it using the actual QnAMaker.ai Test function. Included that now.

Comment: You've left out the part where you've created a bot from a QnA Maker knowledge base. What do you mean by a no-code solution? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Thanks for the comment. The bot has been created using push-button deployment through both QnAMaker and also Microsoft Azure. I created the knowledgebase on the QnAMaker site - that took me through how to set up a bot within the cognitive services on Azure. As this is a PoC and not something I want to maintain moving forwards I'd like the coding aspect to be as abstract as possible. I don't want to have to open the solution in order to add AdaptiveCards when it appears they should work when implemented through QnAMaker.

Comment: @MikeSmith - What is your question? And would you be willing to accept an answer that says it's impossible, or would you only accept an answer that explains how to do it?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - if it's not possible then that's simply a limitation of the current solution, right? No prblems there. My confusion is that it appears that you should be able to (essentially) copy-paste JSON into the QnAMaker.ai site via New QnAPair and have that show Adaptive Cards (as shown on the livetiles website) but when I'm following the exact same steps it's not working. This would be useful as that means that a rich content bot could be implemented easily and quickly.

Comment: @KyleDelaney


I'd love to be able to do the following...
- Open the QnAMaker.ai site
- Select my Knowledge Base
- Create a new QnA Pair
- Paste correctly formatted JSON into the Answer field
- Click Save and Train
- Click Test
- Ask the appropriate question that triggers the JSON-based answer
- Have the embedded AdaptiveCard dicplay in the chat window (this could be a form, a video, a contact card or anything else listed on the AdaptiveCard documentation)

Comment: @KyleDelaney To properly answer your question: "What is your question?" My question is probably this; 'Why does my AdaptiveCard JSON not appear as an AdaptiveCard when I trigger it in the Bot Framework Emulator?'

Does this help? I know there is a lot of information in this post so I might be making things a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below json it works for me ,

```
{
  //"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
  //"content": {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "Image",
        "url": "",
        "size": "stretch",
        "selectAction": {
          "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
          "title": "Test",
          "url": "https://www.livetiles.nyc/"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "This is an adaptive card - if this renders it means it's worked!",
        "wrap": true
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Let's get started!",
        "url": "Let's get started!"
      }
    ]
  //}
}
```

[image]

I have added a screenshot below please check
[image]

```
code for send card as an attachment :
 var cardAttachment = Common.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: how are you adding this to the bot? Through QnAMaker? Would you be able to show me through a screenshot?

Comment: So this is in the actual solution within Visual Studio? I assumed that this was through the QnAMaker site.

Comment: yes we used visual studio for making a bot application.